# Зависания при удалении из списка map

Tags: javascript, map

Есть список на 2 миллиона записей и функция, каждый раз обрабатывающая и удаляющая 100 тыс. записей (map.delete). Список глобальный. Первые проходы обрабатываются быстро, записи удаляются, список уменьшается. Но чем дальше, тем дольше выполняется операция. Хотя вроде бы должно быть наоборот, список становится меньше. Если бы все тормозило сразу, то было бы понятно, что ресурсов не хватает. Но здесь программа несколько десятков раз выполняется быстро, и ближе к концу списка начинает висеть. В чем может быть проблема, и как с этим можно бороться? Среда браузера.

```
for (let i=1;i<100000;i++){
    const arr = all_tikets.entries()
    let idx = arr.next().value    
    // код    
    if (idx[1]>0){
        // код
    }
    else {
        // код
    }
    all_tikets.delete(idx[0])
    delete idx  // добавил, но проблему это не решило
}
```

Comment: Через консоль проверяйте?

Comment: Первое, посмотрите в сторону [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). Далее, вы каждую итерацию создаете новый массив arr и очень может быть, что ваш сборщик мусора не справляется

Comment: Если покажите ваш проблемный код полностью(ну основные моменты), то возможно найдется решение. Пока мы можем только гадать, что такое **all_tikets**, что за метод **all_tikets.delete** и зачем вы пытаетесь удалить переменную...

Comment: На сборщик мусора я никак повлиять не могу? Функция для одной записи, поэтому неоптимальная. Можно оптимизировать ее, если перенести for на третью строчку, пока писал вопрос уже придумал. Но вопрос оставил, все-таки непонятно. Список уменьшается, а время обработки растет.

Comment: all_tikets.delete это стандартное Map.delete (key) - удаление записи из словаря

Comment: Сколько элементов у вас в all_tikets? И точно ли idx[0] возвращает желаемое вам значение? Сборщиком можно управлять, но лучше не допускать избыточного потребления памяти

Comment: Да все работает на малых числах, для 1, для 100 записей, и даже для 10 тыс. работает сначала нормально, но дальше все тормозит по 5-10 сек, но все равно работает. Слабое место all_tikets.entries - оно и отжирает память. Вопрос больше в том, как принудительно запустить сборщик, потратить на это пусть несколько секунд, чтобы дальше работало быстро.

Comment: Вам надо менять алгоритм, а не заниматься сборщиком. Вот зачем вы каждую итерацию получаете полные данные из all_tikets?

Comment: @SwaD, `entries` - итератор возвращает, о каких "полных" данных речь идет?

Comment: @ScorpyOn, `delete idx` - эта строка вообще ничего не делает

Comment: Все повторяется, если **полностью** убрать код между `let idx = arr.next().value` и `all_tikets.delete(idx[0])`?

Answer (score -1):

Ну в общем сдвинул for на одну строчку вниз - все стало летать. Для этой задачи нет необходимости на каждом проходе делать entries(). Изначально функция была для одного прохода, без for и вызывалась много раз, for я добавил сюда для наглядности. Теперь переделал для N записей. Получается тормоза создавал all_tikets.entries() Всем спасибо!